# VB.NET - How To Get Raw Image Data To String

Tags: vb.net, image-processing, httpwebrequest, gdi

How would I get raw image data to a String in VB.NET similar to the following:

```
J©õÝ¨e‚Lnž¿Ëã/Ç§úÐ5ý¼C÷Cý>ß’t;fm—=Äw:�/E±ËÙÏ$á@%Pc>×    Šgw.²Ab“:ÅÓù:Ï¯Ìh6à€Z§Ó‚g£®hÚD6¨Ø^Ú2ô`ä¨L�YÆÄÅCX#I“ÈÌãj¦L˜•’|¥�Eb¡ëQ–¤Ú, 3\UzL  öÔoj4�•±’u«c¼#„oÕ`îF>·o—ŠûÅ«ÎÑ™¶Ç˜ýº*i°œÈVŒ�Qû”Ñ[.�ÔmçE•ì¦eNCh�Ù
é§�É$m¿ôš"»ÌNæ(VÌmp›F¹XÈ88™ªüµ…d•XµÔÜ#�ˆŠv‘º‚F‚§Yûb
```

My current code is:

```
Dim FileName As String = "Image.jpg"
Dim ImageData() As Byte = File.ReadAllBytes(ProfileImagePath)
Dim NewImageData As String = Convert.ToBase64String(ImageData)
```

This returns the Base64 code but I am trying to get the actual raw data like in the example above so that I can POST to a multipart upload form which also posts in this way.

My full code for the upload being:

```
Dim boundary As String = "-----------------------------" & DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x")
        Dim req As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("http://www.mysite.com/upload.php"), HttpWebRequest)
        req.Method = "POST"
        req.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" & "---------------------------" & DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x")
        req.KeepAlive = False
        Dim builder As New StringBuilder()
        builder.Append(boundary & vbCrLf & "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""variable1""" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "1" & vbCrLf)
        builder.Append(boundary & vbCrLf & "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""file""; filename=""" & FileName & """" & vbCrLf)
        builder.Append("Content-Type: application/octet-stream")
        builder.Append(vbCrLf & vbCrLf)
        ' Add Photo Here
        If UpdateImage = True Then
            ' Load Image
            Dim ImageData() As Byte = File.ReadAllBytes(ProfileImagePath)
            Dim NewImageData As String = Convert.ToBase64String(ImageData)
            ' Add Image To Header
            builder.Append(NewImageData)
            builder.Append(vbCrLf)
        Else
            builder.Append(vbCrLf)
        End If
        builder.Append(boundary & vbCrLf & "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""save""" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "save")
        ' Footer Bytes
        Dim close As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("--")
        Dim postHeader As String = builder.ToString()
        Dim postHeaderBytes As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postHeader)
        Dim boundaryBytes As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(vbCrLf & boundary & "--" & vbCrLf)
        Dim length As Long = postHeaderBytes.Length + boundaryBytes.Length
        req.ContentLength = length
        Dim requestStream As Stream = req.GetRequestStream()
        Dim fulllength As Integer = postHeaderBytes.Length + boundaryBytes.Length
        ' Write out our post header
        requestStream.Write(postHeaderBytes, 0, postHeaderBytes.Length)
        ' Write out the trailing boundary
        requestStream.Write(boundaryBytes, 0, boundaryBytes.Length)
        Dim responce As WebResponse
        responce = req.GetResponse()
        requestStream.Close()
        Dim s As Stream = responce.GetResponseStream()
        Dim sr As New StreamReader(s)
        Dim Content As String = sr.ReadToEnd()
```

Comment: Don't do that.  You should use byte arrays.

Comment: They question on everyone's lips is, "Why?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> This returns the Base64 code but I am trying to get the actual raw data like in the example above

The "actual raw data" **isn't text data** so you shouldn't put it in a string at all; at least not without something like base64.

If you want to post binary data, then *either* use base64 *or* post it as raw bytes, but *not* as text. Your data is *not* UTF-8-encoded text, so don't try to use it as if it were.

(I can't remember the details of multi-part form data; if you can specify a part length before the part itself, then you should be fine to include the binary data directly. If it's *always* just delimited by some separator, then you may want to use base64 instead.)